# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController navigation barStyle BlackTranslucent dislocates layout

Tags: iphone, ios, abpeoplepickerview, peoplepicker

with bar style as `BlackOpaque` my people picker looks like:
[image]

but when I want the barStyle to be `BlackTranslucent`, it looks like this:
[image]

I have tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287672/uinavigationcontroller-barstyle-property-changes-layout)

CODE:

```
- (void)showPeoplePickerController
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty],[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty],nil];

picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

//  picker.navigationBar.translucent = YES; //uncommented for translucent bar


[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

But how do I shift things from PeoplePicker down?

Comment: Share some code...how you add ABPeoplePickerNavigationController navigation barStyle...

Answer (score 0):

OK In place of this:

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

Display your ABPeoplePickerNavigationController like below:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And for bar color check this line: `picker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];`

Comment: i don't think this is the solution to the problem I am facing. on iOS4.2, tintcolor will not work, and presentviewcontroller works on iOS6, but how to solve the issue that on translucent bar, the tableview goes up?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a translucent navigation bar in the first place? The people picker view controller isn't meant to be used with a translucent navigation bar.

If you have a good reason to do so, you'd need to do some hacking to get the content to be displayed correctly:
You have to modify the `contentInset` property of the displayed table view so that the content starts below the navigation bar.

**BUT:** There's no way to access the displayed table view, sorry.